# Convert date in string to DateTime C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, datetime

I get dates in these formats:

```
07 December, 2012
7 December, 2012
December 07, 2012
12/07/2012
12/7/2012
```

in a string variable from which I have to identify date, month, year. The date can be a string in any of the above format. I was wondering there must be a code that can handle all possibilities of date as string data type. I mean I want to pass date as string and get DateTime object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if DateTime.TryParse() handles them all properly, but it would be the first thing I'd try.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx

Comment: or DateTime.TryParseExact()

Comment: Thanks DateTime.TryParse() works well.

Comment: This won't work for any cultures. Apart from that, if the question was to to ensure that given strings can be parsed to DateTime. `TryParse` can not ensure that, it can only ensure that no exception is raised. Also, `TryParseExact` would be better since it allows to use a custom format string.

Comment: @Tim - along with this, `Try Parse` validates if the date string passed is correct? that's the beauty of `TryParse`. So I will  say +1 Dennis

Comment: @Tim - I am afraid to say - that we can even get valid dates when the type is string.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) with all possible allowed formats:

```
var strings = new[] { "07 December, 2012", "7 December, 2012", "December 07, 2012", "December 07, 2012", "12/07/2012", "12/7/2012" };
var formats = new[]{"dd MMMM, yyyy", "d MMMM, yyyy", "MMMM dd, yyyy", "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd/M/yyyy"};
var dates = strings
    .Select(s => DateTime.ParseExact(s, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None));
foreach(DateTime d in dates)
    Console.WriteLine("Year:{0} Month:{1} Day:{2}", d.Year , d.Month , d.Day);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/zApbXX)

I have used `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` to enforce the date separator `/` which is normally the date-separator of your current culture(see [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator)).

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Parse("date string" )
```